# How to say "I'll work hard for the whole semester"

Tags: adjective, expression

How can I say "I'll work hard for the whole semester" in German?

> Ich arbeite schwer das ganze Semester lang.

Is it okay to use the adjective "lang" here?

Or

> Ich arbeite schwer für das ganze Semester.

Comment: Der, die oder das - Semester ist sächlich, also das ganze Semester. Und nun zur eigentlichen Frage ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ich werde das ganze Semester (lang) hart arbeiten.

**Hard** translates to **hart** here, the second verb (arbeiten) has to come final, future has to be used so as to distinguish the statement from a mere description of what you're doing, **lang** is optional and finally, it is **das Semester** so no "den"

Comment: Does "schwer" simply not work?

Comment: @Kunal... not in this context. "Schwer" is proper if you talk about physical labor.

Comment: Schwer arbeiten wird auch für geistige Arbeit verwendet, für kreative und für lang dauernde wie auch für ermüdende, weil es schwer ist durchzuhalten.

Comment: @userunknown... ich glaube wenn einer sagt "Ich habe die ganze Nacht schwer gearbeitet" dann assoziieren die meisten damit körperlich. Hast du ein Beispiel?

Comment: @Emanuel: Wenn ich weiß, dass derjenige Philosoph oder Autor ist, dann nehme ich an er hat gelesen oder geschrieben und nicht die Wand aufgestemmt - schon wegen der Nachbarn.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think that instead of "hart" a better translation would be "I werde das ganze Semester **fleißig** arbeiten"?

Fleißig "unermüdlich und zielstrebig arbeitend, arbeitsam" 
See Duden https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fleiszig#Bedeutunga

Answer (score 0):

Du kannst auch so sagen : Ich arbeite schwer ( od. hart)  das ganze Semester lang.

Du kannst aber das "lang" weglassen.

Comment: Hart passt an sich besser.

Comment: you can't say that because the aspect of future is missing. You can use present tense if yu have a clear time indication fr "when" but you don't have that here. "Semester" is an indication of Duration.

Comment: Axo. Danke, dass du mich korrigiert hast. :)

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to stress that he or she will work relentlessly you might also say „Ich werde das ganze Semester ÜBER hart arbeiten.“